# Gulp + Bootstrap Fonts

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

To put it simply, I have the following file structure:

```
frontend
├── bower_components
│   └── bootstrap
│       └── dist
│           ├── css
│           │   └── bootstrap.css
│           └── fonts
│               └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│
├── src
│   ├── style
│   │   └── main.sass
│   └── index.html
│
└── gulpfile.js
```

In `main.sass` I directly import bootstrap file:

```
@import ../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

But it automatically changes link to font from

`../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`

to

`../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`.

What I want to get after building with Gulp is this structure:

```
build
├── css
│   └── main.css
├── fonts
|   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
└── index.html
```

How should I correctly build everything to get link in `main.css` to `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've abandoned import of .css files in favor of gulp-concat. Works fine. Sourcemapping is correct, too.

```
gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    var cssStream = gulp.src(path.bower.bootstrap.css);

    var sassStream = gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write());

    var mergedStream = merge(cssStream, sassStream)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));

    return mergedStream;
});
```